# How to make a for loop to update all the rows of a column in sqlite with numbers

Tags: python, sqlite

i want to make a 'for' loop function such that upon deletion or addition of a new row will decrease or increase the number in the column. basically i want to make a "Sl.no" column for my database which will correct itself with addition or deletion of rows.

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('time.db')
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute(''' CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS time(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, sl real)''')
conn.commit()


for sl in range(100):
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO time VALUES(NULL, :sl)",{'sl':sl})

conn.commit()

cur.execute("SELECT sl FROM time")

fulllist = cur.fetchall()
print(fulllist)
print("next"'\n')


print(len(fulllist))

print("next"'\n')

cmy=[]

for dx in fulllist:
    for cx in dx:
        cmy.append(cx)

print(cmy)
print( str(len(cmy)) +'\n' +'next'+'\n')


for slx in range(1,len(cmy)+1):
    cur.execute('''UPDATE time SET sl=:sl WHERE id=:id ''',{'sl':slx, 'id':id})
    conn.commit()
    print(slx)

print("slno_setting"+'\n')



cur.execute("SELECT sl FROM time")
newlist = cur.fetchall()
print(newlist)
```

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve with this?  There may be better approaches - looping overall the rows will get slower and  slower as the number of rows increases.

Comment: @snakecharmerb i am a beginner and i was making a gui based app with python and tinker, the app stores data using sqlite3, it displays the stored database in tkinter treeview widget, but once you delete an entry, the column that displays "slno" shows the previous assigned digit which is why i have been trying to find a way such that it displays new 'digit'.The app is blood sugar record keeper, so the user types glucose to record .The code is in other question <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64060874/update-flaw-in-my-python-tkinter-sqlite-application>.I am willing to learn better approach

Comment: Assuming that the purpose of this digit is _decorative_ - it's just to show a row number in the GUI - I would probably not store it, but use the [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) built-in function to generate it when the table is displayed.

Comment: @snakecharmerb oh i will use this, thanks